# apache solr provisioning - how to keep config in VCS but data on machine

Tags: solr, provisioning, vagrant-provision

I need to make some adoptions in project that utilizes apache solr for fulltext searches. Someone configured everything on the production machine and i want to prepare everything locally and deploy the whole new version at once.

I already created working vagrant setup for everything and it works well.

But my problem is - i am not very experienced with configuring apache solr and cant manage to get it working.

Here is my installation script:

```
apt-get install -q -y openjdk-8-jdk

# install apache solr
if [[ ! -e "/etc/default/solr.in.sh" ]]
then
    wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/7.7.1/solr-7.7.1.tgz
    tar xzf solr-7.7.1.tgz solr-7.7.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
    chmod u+x ./install_solr_service.sh
    ./install_solr_service.sh solr-7.7.1.tgz
    cat /vagrant/config/solr/solr.in.sh >> /etc/default/solr.in.sh
    rm -f /opt/solr-7.7.1/server/solr/solr.xml
    ln -s /vagrant/config/solr/solr.xml /opt/solr-7.7.1/server/solr/solr.xml
fi
```

contents of /vagrant/config/solr/solr.in.sh

*(content taken from production config - i dont really understand the purpose)*

```
# this is just a partial file - we append its contents to the original
SOLR_RECOMMENDED_OPEN_FILES=65000
```

Content of linked solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr>

<str name="coreRootDirectory">${coreRootDirectory:/vagrant/config/solr/cores}</str>

<solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>

</solrcloud>

<shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:}</str>
</shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

The cores directory contains all the information from the production machine, i just added the following value to the `core.properties` file within each core

```
dataDir=/var/solr/data/NAME_OF_CORE
```

I figured this way the data would be part of my machine but the config part of my repository.

But when i browse to localhost:8983 (which works perfectly) i dont see any core. Neither can i create a new core, when creating a new core called "new_core" it says:

```
new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core new_core: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

So - how would i provision solr correctly to keep all my config in git but the data on the machine?

The company that set up everything is not helpful, they provide ZERO information.

Kind regards,
Philipp

Comment: The information about `zk` (zookeeper) in the configuration files indicates that the current setup uses Solr in the cloud mode. In that case all the (real) configuration files are stored in Zookeeper and can be [retrieved and uploaded with the bundled `zkcli.sh` script](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/command-line-utilities.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, do you have any resource/link for me, that helps me getting rid of cloud/zk crap - i just want it to work without any centralization bs

Comment: The whole point of cloud/zk is to avoid centralization :-) But you can use downconfig with the tool, then place the schema etc. under the configsets for the local core and use it that way.

Comment: maybe i could - but thats why i am here - i cant